# If I set the request method to GET, 415(Unsupported Media Type) occured in Swagger

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

It is my source code like the followings. And Swagger UI generated the followings html for the document. But if I call this api, it fix the content type as "text-plain" even if I set the application/json type. So 415 error occured. If I change the request method to POST, it is ok.. How can I solve this? It is a bug, right?

```
@ApiOperation(value = "TLINK 기능적합율 수집 조회", notes = "기능 적합율 복합지표를 위한 TLINK 기능적합율 연계", 
        httpMethod = "GET",  consumes = "application/json",  produces = "application/json",  
        protocols = "http, https", nickname = "T-Link 기능지표 조회", response = TLink.class)
@ApiResponses(value = {@ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Process error"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 405, message = "Invalid input"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 415, message = "Bad format")})
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces= "application/json", consumes = "application/json")
public
@ResponseBody
List<TLink> selectAPI(@ApiParam(name = "tlink", required = true, value = "TLink")
        @RequestBody TLink tLink) {
    logger.info("select api of TLink is triggered. tlink = {}", tLink.toString());
    return select(tLink);
}
```

Comment: Leave the `GET` and try to remove the `consumes = "application/json"` part

Comment: @alfasin it doesn't work.  
  "timestamp": 1440740211770,
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
  "message": "Required request body content is missing: org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod$HandlerMethodParameter@72470d53",
  "path": "/api/v1/tlinks"
}

Comment: Are you using the latest version of [swagger-ui](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui)?

Comment: @wing328 I am using [swagger4springweb](https://github.com/wkennedy/swagger4spring-web). it is written that it supports swaager 1.3.

Comment: swagger4springweb seems not active (last update almost a year ago). I would recommend you to use [springfox](https://github.com/springfox/springfox) instead

Comment: @wing328 thanks. but I have never heard about springfox. does it have low learning curve and is similar to swagger4springweb?

Comment: can't comment on that as i do not have much experience with their latest version.